# Copy values to another column - ORA-01481: invalid number format model

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

I want to copy values of **col1 NUMBER(13,4)** column to another newly added **col1_temp VARCHAR2(50)**. To perform this action I build the following update query:

```
update table1 set col1_temp = to_char(col1, '99.99%');
```

Here is the current view of both columns:

```
 col1  |  col1_temp
-------------------
 13.9  |  null
 65.7  |  null
 21.63 |  null
 50.5  |  null
 10.8  |  null
 30.1  |  null
```

But running of the query gives me back always this error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-01481: invalid number format model
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you want copy the data in the first place? Why no just create a view that returns the formatted number?

Answer (score 3):

`%` is not a valid format specifier for numbers.

See the documentation below:

[Number Format Models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00211)

Answer (score 0):

Do it with:

```
update table1 set col1_temp = to_char(col1, '99.99')||'%';
```

Also be careful. Your `col1` can hold bigger values than 99.99. These values will give ###### as a result and also the value will be rounded on 2 decimals by the `to_char` command.